# Set the position of the custom dialog box in android?

Tags: android, dialog

We have create a custom dialog box.

How do we set the custom dialog box at the `Middle` of the center position.

Sample code is `dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`

Now custom dialog box is displayed at the `Top` Of the center position.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see below links it is default in CENTER.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Answer (score 1):

TestAActivity.java

package com.TestA;

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class TestAActivity extends Activity {
        private Button btn;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        // TwitPicResponse tpResponse = null;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    show_Dialog();
                }
            });

        }

        protected void show_Dialog() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(TestAActivity.this);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test);
            dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            dialog.show();
        }
    }

enter code here
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout_root"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="10dp"
              >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
               />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is full demo code of custom dialog box.if you use this ans correct this.